# Client To Server DHCP Virtual Setup

Tags: networking, windows-7, windows-server-2008, vmware, dhcp

I have properly configured a server and client setup with VMware, I can connect to the server with the client if I input the IPV4 information in manually, instead of having it obtain the ip and dns automatically. Since it is a VMware machine, it naturally assigns to the underlying host it is on, as I have set it to "Host-only: A private network shared with the host".

My main question would be, is there anyway to release from this dhcp server and connect to the other on request, and if so, what would be the best way to do that?

**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

- Using VMware Player.
- Windows Server 2008 (Server)
- Windows 7 Home Edition (Client)
- Yes dhcp server is configured, and yes it is recognized when
  connected and on it own domain within the local network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution after some reading, kinda just hit me, surprised I didn't think of it before, a lot of people were saying you couldn't choose which DHCP to have your computer/client connect to, which is kind of silly. I blocked the IP address in the firewall, of the incoming server dhcp requesting IP address that I didn't want to connect to, so that the other request is the only one it could receive. This way it connected to that DHCP server with the automatic DHCP options that I needed to test. For anyone who comes across something similar.